# Managing Interactions - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Having some trouble managing interactions between slicers and graphs in PowerBI.

1. Some visuals are showing as not having an interaction to manage even though they change when the slicer is changed (when i say no interaction i mean there is no option to block the interaction).
2. I am using a line graph linked to a slicer, the data is working as it should until i try to lock in the results for one particular sub group and then block any further interactions with the visual, when i do this the data then changes.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Lee

Answer (score 0):

For your questions:

1. Every visual allows you to `Edit Interaction`, however, if you have a lot of visuals and some of them are for example on the top of your page, the icon for editing can appear invisible, however, if you move the visual to a place where there is space above the visual, it will show up (`I just tested it, all visuals that were on top *(and there were other visuals below them)*, didn't show the interaction button`).
   ***So basically, move the original visual a bit, edit the interaction and put it back when it was.***
2. If you want to show only one group in a certain visual, use the `filter on this visual` and then `block any interactions` with other visuals.